# JQuery checkbox when value is assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, opencart

I've been trying to get JQuery to check a radio for me when I assign a value 'Z' to it.
My current code:

```
       <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
        <div class="form-group<?php echo ($option['required'] ? ' required' : ''); ?>">
          <label class="control-label"><?php echo $option['name']; ?></label>
          <div id="input-option<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>">
            <?php if (isset($option_values)) foreach ($option_values as $option_value) { ?>

            <div class="radio">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
                <?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>

                <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>  
                <?php  if ($option_value['price_prefix'] == 'z') {?> 
                <script>
                $(".radio").prop("checked", true)
                </script>   
                <?php echo 'Im Active!!'; ?><?php } 
                    else { ?> <?php echo ' ';?> (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix'];?>                
                <?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>) <?PHP }?>                     
                <?php } ?>

              </label>
            </div>

            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

      <?php } ?>
```

As for now, my option 'Z' only shows 'I'm Active!!' in the list. The radio is still unchecked though. 
What am I doing wrong?

I'm planning on releasing a free OpenCart module where people can activate an option by standard by assigning the value Z in product properties.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, mixing logic of PHP and JS (comparing with `"z"` using PHP and setting `checked` using JS) is not a good idea at all. About question: I don't see any element with ID `radio` in your page.

Comment: I've added some more context code. The element ID should be 'Input-option <?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>'. Why shouldn't this be a good idea?

Comment: Well, now you've added class `radio` to `<div>` and are setting `checked` to this `<div>`. Let's just say that it is useless. `checked` has to be set to `<input type="radio">`